# Parser with objects of custom class as a tokens

Tags: java, parsing

Looking for java parser generator that accept objects of custom class implementing Comparable interface (or perhaps some parser-specific interface) as an input tokens in resulting parser.
ANTLR seems to be too character stream-oriented.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Generally I use [JavaCC](http://javacc.java.net/). It is very simple and you can produce what you want.

Here you can find a simple [tutorial](http://www.engr.mun.ca/~theo/JavaCC-Tutorial/javacc-tutorial.pdf).